# Under what circumstances will a layout element be null when fetched using findViewById(R.id.*)?

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, r.java-file

I have a layout as below:

Let's name it `my_layout.xml`:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#19396a"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#19396a"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/uilistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity I have a method in which I initialize all the UI elements i.e I do mapping of activity UI variables to layout.

Assume, the method is as below:-

```
//used to initialize UI elements
//called in oncreate() method
public void initializeUIelements() {
......
activity_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.uilistView);
}
```

Here, `activity_listView`  is a class level variable of type `ListView`

In my project, I have `res\layout` as well as `res\layout-land` and `my_layout.xml` exists in both the folders.

But sometimes during activity restart/when it's created I get a `NullpointerException` while initializing `activity_listView` that comes from `R.java`.

**I know:**

> We get `NullpointerException` similar to what I am asking when an
>   element does not exist in any of the layout folder(i.e it exists in layout-land but does not exist in layout folder).

But here,the element exists in both folders and even though I get this inconsistent error
i.e. I am not able to produce it always but sometimes it starts coming.

So,please help me in analyzing as what may be the reasons when we get this error apart from the one mentioned by me above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a more specific example, it might be easier to debug the exact problem. A few reasons why your View might be null:

**The layout you've set as the content view does not include a view with this id:**

If you reference a View that exists in the R file (a file that holds references to all elements within the `res` folder), say `uilistview`, in an Activity where you are not setting it's layout container as the content view (in this case this would be my_layout.xml), you will not get an error in Eclipse or whatever IDE you are using. Android will look for a View with this `id` within the layout, and if it can't find it, it will return a null value.

**You call findViewById too early**

You must use the method `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)` before you try to access any of the elements with `findViewById()`. Logically, it makes sense - you need to tell Android where it should look where it's find an element

**Looking for an element inside an inflated View**

This is similar to the first, but it's common. If you've inflated a view and then want to manipulate a View inside the inflated View, you must instruct Android to look in the right place. For example:

```
RLayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View smallerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout);
```

If you want to reference something within `mylayout.xml`, you would need to use this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) smallerView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

rather than:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

The first indicates to look into the inflated view by placing the `findViewById` method on the inflated view, while the second one applies it to the current View of the Activity, which will cause a null value to be return.

**Clean your project**

This is the most frustrating answer, because this is not your fault. Sometimes the R.java class messes up and causes wrong references to id's while it is being compiled/built. Try cleaning your project and correcting the wrong references by looking for `Project -> Clean` in the main bar of Eclipse (or the IDE you're using).